# How to do a unitary diagonalization of a normal matrix?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

It is easy to diagonalize a normal matrix such that $D = P^{-1} A P$ by simply putting all the orthogonal eigenvectors as columns for $P$. But I spent hours trying a unitary diagonalization of the following Hermitian (and therefore Normal) matrix:
$$  A =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & i & 1 \\
    -i & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} $$
such that $ D = U^*AU $. I know that by definition every normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable. The eigenvalues of this matrix are $ \{ 0, -\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \} $.

What did not work but was my most promising try, was to scale down the eigenvectors by their norm so the matrix $ P $ became orthonormal. The result does not give me the diagonal matrix with the desired eigenvalues though.
Also, Google search did not yield a single nicely explained way to do a unitary transform of a normal matrix. The only document that I believe to try to explain it is [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/diag_11.pdf), although it does not show clearly how to construct $ U $.

Comment: Note that the Matlab expression U' returns the conjugate transpose of U for matrices U with complex entries and that U.' returns the nonconjugate transpose.  I'm guessing that your promising try was correct, but your verification failed.

Comment: Nearly! My try was not correct since I didn't normalize properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0, \sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$. These eigenvalues correspond to the eigenvectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
i\\
1
\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2}\\
-i\\
1
\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sqrt{2}\\
-i\\
1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
respectively. You will observe that the eigenvectors are orthogonal with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Normalizing the eigenvectors gives the unitary matrix 
$$
U = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{2}\\
i/\sqrt{2} & -i/2 & -i/2\\
1/\sqrt{2} & 1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that diagonalizes $A$ to $D = \operatorname{diag}(0,\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Absolutely. I failed to orthonormalize properly with respect to the standard inner product in $\mathbb{C}^n$ as you showed. Thanks!

Comment: Is any diagonalizable matrix can be in the form $ U D {U}^{H} $ or there are special requirements for that?

Comment: Only the normal matrices are unitarily diagonalizable. A matrix $A$ is normal if $A^*A = AA^*$.